# How to broadcast mp4 stream

Tags: broadcasting

I have mp4 stream available over HTTP to single client

How to broadcast it to multiple clients?

I can write code that will read MP4 stream over HTTP and copy to multiple clients.

But is there some initial frame, header in MP4 stream?

May be some framework or existing server can broadcast mp4 stream?

Answer (score 1):

Use VLC, it has nice streaming possibilities (*VLC* is for *Video Lan Client*, by the way).

Just fire up VLC, go to File->Stream..., select the source you want to distribute, choose e.g. http as method, transcode (or don't), and select the port to listen on. From there on, your clients can connect :)

Comment: Do you know command line command to read stream http://192.168.0.101/stream.mp4 and make it available on port 80 I think there is command line version of VLC.

Comment: Is it possible to stream more then 1 HTTP stream with VLC on single HTTP port?

Comment: yes. As I wrote, VLC can serve arbitrary numbers of clients.

Comment: By the way, videolan.org is the official VLC website. Please feel encouraged to read their documentation.